# In DocuSign how can i generate my integrator key for the production org?

Tags: docusignapi

In DocuSign how can i generate my integrator key for the production org and go live? Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Before you go live with your API integration, you need to enable one of your developer demo account integrator keys in a live production account. To enable your key, you need to pass a quick, automated review process, which is accessible from your developer demo account.

See this [documentation](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-api-and-keys#To4)